Why does java not give compile error when inserting non comparable objects in Tree based collection
Why is it so that java don't give compile time error when inserting objects in Tree based collections.
It does gives runtime exception. But wouldn't it be great if it gives compile error.
Code :
import java.util.*;


class Dog{
    int size;
    Dog(int s){
        size = s;
    }

}


public class Test01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Dog> set = new TreeSet<Dog>();
        set.add(new Dog(1));
        set.add(new Dog(2));
        set.add(new Dog(3));
    }
}

It compiles perfect. On runtime it gives ClassCastException complaining that Dog cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Does this answer your question? What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?

I did use generics also.

First, you're using a raw type (or you were before the edit). Don't do that. Second, the type parameter of TreeSet is just T extends Object, so it can be used with element types that don't implement Comparable. Why? Because you can create a tree set with a Comparator.

If I were to design TreeSet, I would not give it a no-argument constructor. I would force passing a Comparator<T> and then provide a static convenience method for element types that are naturally comparable (i.e., implement Comparable). But that's not how the class was designed. Instead, the no-argument constructor is the "convenience method", meaning there's no way for the compiler to enforce the element type be Comaprable.

@Slaw Yes. Got your point. Someone just mentioned it DOES have comparator constructor, but as you said its not made mandatory & due to no-argument constructor, it is happening this way.

There's a bit of a history in Java of designing APIs where "natural order" is specified either by not passing a comparator or by passing null, but then provide no way of enforcing the type be comparable. Granted, TreeSet was added to the standard library before generics were part of the language. But the no-argument constructor seems like something that could have been deprecated (though possibly never for removal in order to maintain backwards compatibility).
